# What is the right syntax for jsp:include?

Tags: jsp, jspinclude

My application is a hybrid of Servlets and Spring.

Most pages are divided in subsections, included in the main jsp using jsp:include.
I'm having some issues when the target of the import is a REST call instead of an actual JSP page.

I had to change the paths from `"../rest/xyz"` to `"${contextPath}/rest/xyz"` because sometimes the first version would result in "appName/rest/rest/xyz".

However, I am still facing issues from time to time when there are nested includes: the resulting path is "appName/appName/rest...". I am struggling to find a syntax that works for all the cases.

Is there a better way to do it?

EXAMPLE:

in books.jsp I have

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/library/chapters.jsp"/>
```

then in chapters.jsp I have

```
<jsp:include page="/rest/paragraphs?chapter=x"/>
```

But I cannot get the path to `paragraphs` right:

- `${contextPath}/rest/paragraphs` results in `appName/appName/rest/paragraphs`
- `../rest/paragraphs`  results in `appName/jsp/library/../rest/paragraphs`

Comment: Can you elaborate on some issues you facing?

Comment: @RomanC I already said in the question. When I have nested "include*s I cannot get the right path to the resources

Comment: You should post the code to show how did you do "nested include*s". Also include a code that you do to get "right path to the resources".

Answer (score -1):

It's best practice to declare your paths relative to the root (eg start your  paths with `/`)

```xml
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/foo.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/bar.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="/${contextPath}/rest/xyz" />
```

Comment: The result of `request.getContextPath()`, if any, [already](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getContextPath()) starts with `/`. The last example in your answer would incorrectly generate a double slash like `//appName/rest/xyz`.